# Проблема с кодировкой на стороне сервера Python. Как сделать, чтобы русские символы тоже отображались корректно?

Tags: python, сервер, кодировка, get

Есть сервер, принимающий get запросы. Для удобства делаю get запросы через браузер. как "[http://localhost:8080/Максим](http://localhost:8080/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC)" - вместо русских символов получается белиберда. Вот пример: /%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC

Вот код

```
import os
import socket
import time


# метод ответа на запрос, где data = ответ клиенту
def send_answer(conn, status="200 OK", typ="text/plain; charset=utf-8", data=""):
    data = data.encode("utf-8")
    conn.send(b"HTTP/1.1 " + status.encode("utf-8") + b"\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Server: simplehttp\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Connection: close\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Content-Type: " + typ.encode("utf-8") + b"\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Content-Length: " + bytes(len(data)) + b"\r\n")
    conn.send(b"\r\n")
    conn.send(data)


# обработка get-Запроса. принимает подключение и адрес 
def get_on(conn, addr):
    data = b""

    while not b"\r\n" in data:
        tmp = conn.recv(1024)
        if not tmp:
            break
        else:
            data += tmp

        if not data:
            return

        udata = data.decode("utf-8")  # уже пробовал менять кодировки здесь !!! не помогает 
        udata = udata.split("\r\n", 1)[0]
        method, addres, protocol = udata.split(" ",
                                               2)  # method - тип запроса; addres - параметры запроса (/web/cgi-1.html); protocol - http.1.1 ;

        if method == "GET":
            print(
                addres)  # !!!!!!!!!!! В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ ВМЕСТО /Максим - выводиться белиберда. Как поменять кодировку на нужную?
        send_answer(conn, typ="text/html; charset=utf-8", data=str("otver_cliente"))
    return


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 8080))  # установка Ip(не задано) и порта приема сервера
s.listen(5)

try:
    while 1:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print("New connection from " + addr[0])
        try:
            get_on(conn, addr)
        except:
            send_answer(conn, "500 Internal Server Error", data="Ошибка")
        finally:
            conn.close()
finally:
    s.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote('%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC')  # 'Максим'
```

Comment: спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ! я с этой проблемой 2 сутки маюсь!
здоровья, счастья, денег тебе
прям, от души)))